# Javascript form validation oninput

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to improve my javascript skills with some form validation. Why is my code not working?

```
    <input type="password" id="psw" />
    <p id="demo" ></p>


     <script type="text/javascript" >
        psw.oninput = function(event) {
        myArray = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

    for(x=0; x<myArray.length; x++){
        if(this.value.includes(myArray[x]){
        demo.innerHTML = "password cannot include               
       a number";
    } else{
        demo.innerHTML = "";
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: `Why is my code not working?` Not working how?

Comment: maybe parse and format your code first please?

Comment: Check developer console for possible errors and try using breakpoints and watches to see what exactly is Your code doing inside.

Comment: First your code is not working because you have no `<script>` tag, second what is `psw.oninput`? where is `psw` defined? And finally you can use regex to improve the performance.

Comment: It's working, just not as expected...

Comment: Only when the number nine is entered does the text show up, if you type any other number it doesn't show up. Why?

Comment: The psw is the id for the input

Comment: The last element in your array is the number 9. So when you enter 9, the loop reaches the end and the `innerHTML` is set to "password canno..". When you enter any other number, it loops so fast through the check that even if the `innerHTML` is set to your text, it is then set back to "" (empty) when it reaches the end of the loop. So you don't see anything. A better Idea would be to set `demo.innerHTML = "";`before the loop and then run the loop without the `else` section that empties the `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are some issues with your code

You're trying to bind the `input` event incorrectly

```
psw.oninput = function(event)
    ^
```

Get your element `psw` using the function `getElementById`

```
document.getElementById('psw')
         ^
```

You're assigning a String incorrectly

```
 demo.innerHTML = "password cannot include               
a number";                                ^
^
```

Missing enclosing parenthesis

```
if(this.value.includes(myArray[x])
                                  ^
```

You need to break the loop when this `this.value.includes(myArray[x])` is true.

**Snippet with those fixes**

```js
document.getElementById('psw').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

  for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    if (this.value.includes(myArray[x])) {
      demo.innerHTML = "password cannot include a number ";
      break; // you need to break your loop
    } else {
      demo.innerHTML = "";
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<input type="password" id="psw" />
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could you please explain why a loop break is needed? Kinda confused 

Comment: @MosesChukwudiNwigberi because the loop continues and checks for the next numbers, so when one of the next numbers is not included, the `else` block assigns empty.  Therefore, the loop should break because at least one number was found.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

> Only when the number nine is entered does the text show up, if you type any other number it doesn't show up. Why?

If you enter `5`, it inserts `password cannot include a number`, since it goes through the loop, and since `6` is not present in the string, it clears the alert.

```html
<input type="password" id="psw" />
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" >
     var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
     var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
     psw.oninput = function(event) {
         var isnumberpresent = false;
        myArray = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
        for(var x=0; x<myArray.length; x++)
        {
            if(this.value.includes(myArray[x]))
            {
                isnumberpresent = true;
            }
        }
        demo.innerHTML = isnumberpresent ? "password cannot include a number":"";
    };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic improvement that works. But if you trying to improve your Javascript skills, consider using regular expressions as someone suggested.

```
<input type="password" id="psw" oninput="validate(this.value)" />
        <p id="demo" ></p>

        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function validate(password) {
                var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
                var myArray = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
                for(x=0; x<myArray.length; x++){
                    if(password.includes(myArray[x])){
                        demo.innerHTML = "password cannot include a number";
                        break;
                    } else{
                        demo.innerHTML = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working. Close the if bracket. Use a proper editor for writing code like notepad++.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>
    <input type="text" id="psw"/>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
          var x;
            psw.oninput = function myfunc(){
         var myArray = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
 var ele=document.getElementById("psw").value;
        for(x=0; x<myArray.length; x++){
            if(myArray.includes(ele)){
            demo.innerHTML = "password cannot include a number";
        } 
        else { demo.innerHTML = ""; }
    }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```